# Extract characters from date cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date cell `25/10/2002` in date format with the text format (if i change the format to text) as `37554`. How do i pull the months and year values from this.

If i do `=RIGHT(cell,4)` for the year it pulls out `7554`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
=MONTH(cell)
```

And

```
=YEAR(cell)
```

As it should evaluate text just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **=TEXT(Cell value,"mm-yyyy")** ##will provide you Month and year in MM-YYYY format